# WordPress meta_query for Custom Post Type with orderby

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to sort out a WordPress query for a Custom Post Type, but I can't make it work.

The post type is `events`. An [Advanced Custom Fields](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com) field called `sticky` (yes/no) is used for sorting (stickies on top), and another ACF field called `glamrock` (yes/no) is used to exclude certain posts.

The result is, `glamrock` gets excluded, but stickies are not sorted.

If I delete the `meta_query`, sorting works fine, but `glamrock` posts are included.

```
$bpb_args = array(
  'numberposts'     => -1,
  'post_type'       => 'events',
  'posts_per_page'  => 100,
  'paged'           => get_query_var( 'paged', true ),
  'meta-key'        => 'sticky',
  'meta_query'      => array(
    array(
      'key'     => 'glamrock',
      'value'   => 'no',
      'compare' => 'IN',
    )
  ),
  'orderby'   => 'meta_value',
  'order'     => 'ASC',
);

$bpb_query = new WP_Query( $bpb_args );

if( $bpb_query->have_posts() ):
  while( $bpb_query->have_posts() ) : $bpb_query->the_post();
  //show post
  endwhile;
endif;
```

**Update:**

Unfortunately, `meta_value` instead of `meta_value_num` didn't change anything. It still seems to be sorting by date/time.

The Advanced Custom Field type is Radio Buttons.

In addition to the arguments, I also included the loop.

Comment: `'orderby'   => 'meta_value' `

Comment: your orderby specifics a numeric comparison, where it would seem it's a 'yes' or 'no' value (using your meta query as a point of reference).  @Mihai has it right - change your orderby to simply `meta_value`

Comment: Ouch! Thank you so much, Mihai for solving the problem and cale_b for clarification! Problem solved.

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't change anything, see edit above.

Comment: this may be really old but may still help people newly encountering it... "meta-key" should be `meta_key`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify only `meta_value` since your `meta-key` is non numeric

```
'orderby' => 'meta_value'
```

Answer (score 2):

@Mihai had it right: `meta_value_num` was the main issue. I changed it to `meta_value`.

Here's the query/loop that worked:

```
$args = array(
  'post_type'       => 'events',
  'post_status'     => 'publish',
  'posts_per_page'  => -1,
  'meta_key'        => 'sticky',
  'orderby'         => 'meta_value',
  'order'           => 'ASC',
  'meta_query'      => array(
    array(
      'key'         => 'lizenz_erteilt',
      'value'       => 'no',
      'compare'     => 'LIKE',
    ),
  )
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );

// Loop
if( $query->have_posts() ) :
  while( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
    //show post
  endwhile;
endif;
```